# Why do queries with parameters involving calculations not work in SSRS?

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

Why does this code work in SSRS without issues:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MONTH > :O_MONTH
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MONTH > trunc(:O_MONTH-30)
```

I'm just curious, what is the reason for this? Is there a way around this so I can embed the query for a dataset? When I add the second version of the query that "Define Query Parameter" window pops up, telling me something is wrong.

Please help. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Both queries work in TOAD for example, but the second, the one I need, does not work in Visual Studio. Something about doing the deduction from the input parameter is causing issues. Please help find a way around this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following options.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MONTH > trunc(:O_MONTH) - 30;
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE MONTH > trunc(CAST (:O_MONTH AS DATE)) - 30;
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE MONTH > (CAST :O_MONTH AS DATE) - 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a string, use TO_DATE conversion. For example: trunc(to_date(:o_month,'mm-dd-yyyy'))-30.

Comment: I am passing a date type, so no need for the conversion.

Comment: You may be passing a date but do you know what SSRS is passing the DB? I suggest you try the conversion.

Comment: I actually tried the conversion and it does not work either. I get the error: `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. This is because the value I am passing is typed as a date. I can see that the valued is a date, not a string. Thanks, however.

Comment: Does trunc(:O_MONTH)  work without "-30"? How about if you pass a string and convert to date?

Comment: If something is getting lost in translation, you want to communicate in a way that does not require translation.